# Are there any way to host Azure Mobil Services on MS Hosting Partners?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

We've been working on our first mobil game project and we would like to host it on different geographical regions of the world depending on demands as many game company did. Azure is our preferred cloud environment. For that purpose, we would like to use Microsoft local hosting partners along with Azure own datacenters. If we can do that, we'll be able to minimize and eliminate networking delays. However, local partners do not provide Azure mobil services yet. I wonder whether  is possible with 3rd party solutions or not?

Answer (score 1):

[Azure Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/windows-azure-pack/default.aspx), part of the [Azure Stack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/azure-in-your-datacenter/) for hybrid deployments, is the closest you'll get to having Azure look and feel outside of Azure. It unfortunately does not have anything similar to Mobile Services.